# How to get all the data from a DICOM file with Imebra

Tags: imebra

I am working on a project that integrates Imebra inside an android application. The application is supposed to extract all the data from a given DICOM file and put them into a .xml file. I need a little bit of help with it. For example, I don't know how to get all the VR tags that the given DICOM has, instead of getting them one by one using tag ids. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file using `CodecFactory.load(filename)`.

Then you can use `DataSet.getTags()` to retrieve a list of tags stored into the DICOM structure.

The returned class `TagsIds` is a list containing all the `TagId`: scan each tag ID and retrieve it via `DataSet.getString()` (to retrieve the value as string) and `DataSet.getDataType()` to retrieve its VR.

When `DataSet.getString()` fails then you are dealing with a sequence (an embedded DICOM structure) which can be retrieved with `DataSet.getSequenceItem()`.

You can use the static method `DicomDictionary.getTagName()` to get a description of a particular tag.